# Can a SysTick exception in Cortex-M4 preempt itself?

Tags: c, exception, embedded, cortex-m

I have a handler for SysTick exception which counts ticks and calls other functions (f1, f2, f3) whose execution time can be longer than SysTick period. These functions set and clear their active status (global variables) so if a SysTick exception occurs it can detect an overload and return to interrupted function.

I have assigned fixed priority to SysTick exception (let's say 16). I want to somehow make possible for SysTick to generate an exception regardless of it's prior active status, go to SysTickHandler, increase tick counter and return to interrupted function.

One solution which may be useful is to use BASEPRI. It can be set to priority lower than SysTick so it would enable that exception. Unfortunately, using BASEPRI got me nowhere because nothing happened (I set it to max value). BASEPRI value was 0 inside SysTickHandler before I changed it. Should that value be equal to SysTick priority when processor enters handler function? Is exception priority loaded automatically in BASEPRI?

I have also considered for NVIC to have an issue with preempting already active exception but found nothing regarding that in ARM documentation.

Also, return from handler when oveload is detected could set the processor state to thread mode. Let's ignore that for now.

```
void SysTickHandler(void) { 
    ticks++;
    //set_BASEPRI(max_value);
    if (f1_act || f2_act || f3_act) return;
    else {
        f1();
        f2();
        f3();
    }
}
```

A simpler example for this problem (without return) would be to increase tick counter when having an infinite loop inside handler.

```
void SysTickHandler(void) {
    ticks++;
    set_BASEPRI(max_value);
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: 'calls other functions (f1, f2, f3) whose execution time can be longer than SysTick period' - you should have stopped there and reconsidered your overall design.  Why are you doing so much in an interrupt-handler?

Comment: agreed for periodic interrupts your handler should be much less than the period.  for event based interrupts is where you need to worry about what if I am in the handler, but in general the time in the handlers compared to the expected interrupt rate should be that you are on in handlers a fraction of the time.

Comment: Why use a **periodic** timer for one-shot? That is poor design anyway..

Comment: @MartinJames: on some MCUs you do all processing interrupt-only. The "main-loop" only sleeps. Typical MCU is MSP430. And with prioritisation, you can also do more in the handler (but shall finish in-time, of course!).

Comment: @Olaf : No not on *some processors*, but on *some designs* (bad ones generally).

Comment: As @MartinJames points out, the fact that your interrupt hanler may take significant time is indicitive of bad design, but then you followed it up with mention of *global variables*; so now it is almost  certainly [bad design](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals).

Comment: @Clifford: Not really. MCUs like the MSP430 are especially tailored for such: the sleep/power down bits are in the SR and are pushed on an interrupt, but deasserted in the interrupt. On return, they are restored, thus putting te CPU to sleep. If you have little to do, there is no need for deferred interrupt handlers, etc. But if you only have a hammer ...

Comment: @Olaf : True, but that is still about the design, not the processor - that is not the only mode of operation for MSP430.

Comment: @Clifford: Tell me. For a larger program, I used an event-based coop-mt approach with processing split betwen interrupts and tasks. It just depends. I just triggered at your "bad ones generally". Perhaps you are right as there are too many broken maldesigns in the world. Like the approach of OP here, which is obviously broken (no disagreement about that, I presume:-).

Comment: The code is a sketch of a basic RTOS scheduler (already written in assembler and working on 8051 MPU) which has to execute f1, f2 and f3 code (threads) in handler mode and then return to thread mode where background tasks are. I was just interested if an exception could preempt itself. I wanted to write the same algorithm in C. I think I'm certain now that I'll change the algorithm.
I'll probably go in the direction of setting f1, f2 and f3 as software interrupt handlers with designated priorities and just set pending states from systick interrupt. Seems like a achievable solution

Comment: Sorry, but if you implement an RTOS-scheduler on Cortex-M like on 8051, you definitively do something wrong. The CM was especially designed to support such very cleanly and with a lot of hardware-support (actually even better than Cortex-R/A).

Answer (score 1):

If the interrupt becomes pending while its handler is already running, the handler will run to completion and immediately re-enter.  Your tick will be aperiodic, and if the functions consistently take longer that one tick period, you may never leave the interrupt context.

It may be possible I suppose to increase the priority of the interrupt in the handler so that it will preempt itself, but even if that were to work, I would hesitate to recommend it.

It sounds that what you actually need is an RTOS.

Comment: I don't think that there is such thing as "priority of an interrupt". Priority is a thread-feature. An interrupt occurs as a result of some event (typically a HW event, although it may also be a SW event such as divide-by-zero), which "physicaly" changes the value of the program-counter to point to a different place in the code (the corresponding entry in the interrupt vector). So in a sense, the priority of all interrupts is equal, and higher than that of all the threads in the system (if you are using threads to begin with).

Comment: @barakmanos : The Cortex-M NVIC has pre-emptive interrupt priority assignment.  A higher priority interrupt can indeed interrupt a lower one.

Comment: @Clifford: Just to add: Most 32+ bit CPUs, many DSPs and quite some 16 bit MCUs have similar hardware support. The PC/x86 and most ARM-Cortex-A (mobile, etc) platform included. Even the many smaller 8 bitters have some priorisation hardware (but not necessarily hardware-pre-emption). I'd acctually say that it is the majority nowadays.

Comment: @barakmanos: Interrupts are normally associated with "asynchronous". `divide by zero" or access violation are normally somewhat synchronous and/or related to the flow of control of a thread. IIRC, it is mostly the x86 platform which calls all "interrupt". Many other platforms call the latter "exceptions". And there is always a difference in priority between such exceptions (and between different exceptions) and interrupts.

Comment: I tried to change priority using BASEPRI and NVIC_SetPriority. Both didn't work. I think the main problem is that when the interrupt becomes pending, NVIC compares it's priority to current exception priority which is the changed priority of the SysTick handler, so no matter what I do with it, NVIC can't send "signal" to processor to jump to that handler because the primary condition of preemption (higher priority) isn't met.

Comment: @Clifford: I've worked in the past with STM32, which is an ARM-Cortex based MCU, and there was no interrupt-nesting there. In other words, the context of an interrupt was executed to completion - from entering the IV and until exiting the IV, **including** the ISR (if such one was invoked from the IV). So perhaps it is a matter of how you configure your project...

Comment: @ZvonimirMandic: There are app-notes how to work with the NVIC. IIRC, aslong as the pending flag is set, there will be no further interrupt triggered. However, as Clifford stated, if your functions take longer than the interrupt period your system is either too slow, or your design is broken (which I assume). Handling outside the interrupt will not help here either, unless you can tolerate loosing ticks. And raising the priority is definitively the wrong way. This is normally done if one priority level/vector serves different interrupt sources or tasks.

Comment: @barakmanos: I have the STM32F407 here running at 8.2 proirities with tens of sources. Of course that is not the default settings out of reset. But even then, the sources are prioritised by their vector-number (but without preemption). Also, a MemFault, HardFault or any Interrupt can preempt a SVC, for example even with the default config. And the NVIC is a core-component for the Cortex-M. The Cortex-M has actually even quite sophisticated features like tail-chaining or late-arrival of higher piority interrupts (yes, I really like this design - very well thought).

Comment: @Olaf System design is not broken. This preemption of a system timer is a part of already existing and working simple RTOS on 8051 MPU where that could be achieved. When migrating the code to ARM processor I tried to keep the same algorithm and ended up at this problem. So as it seems I'm changing the algorithm. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: @ZvonimirMandic: 1) ARM Cortex-M has a completely different architecture than 8051. And yes, that design is **apparently** broken. You are asking here, because you have a problem with that now, right? (note that I'm not the only one to tell you).

Comment: @barakmanos : Yes the Cortex-M NVIC is flexible and can run with preemptive or run-to-completion interrupts.  The fact that you have not used a feature of a processor does not make it not exist.

Comment: @ZvonimirMandic : I did not say it would work, and did not take the time to investigate the possibility because it is such an appallingly bad idea.  My first paragraph answers your question.  You probably need to ask a different question, and the answer is still probably to use an RTOS.  If that is what you used on 8051, why not here also?

Comment: @Clifford This code is a sketch of a scheduler for RTOS. I am writing a RTOS for ARM based on a RTOS for 8051. The differences between architectures have led me to this problem. The problem is easily solved for 8051 architecture. I have already found a different way to write this scheduler and I just wanted to make sure that I'm right about not using self preemptive SysTick.

Comment: @ZvonimirMandic : A fundamental principle of an RTOS is that it is deterministic.  An interrupt handler that may or may not complete in one tick period is hardly deterministic, so you are clearly *not* developing an RTOS worthy of the name since you have broken this principle.

Comment: @Clifford Well obvioulsy I couldn't copy-paste the whole code here for everyone to see. The interrupt handler that doesn't complete in one tick period isn't an issue. The system where this is used is very specific so it has very specific needs.

Comment: @ZvonimirMandic : The consensus is against you on this. In an RTOS, all threads are delayed by interrupts, so an interrupt taking that long is a problem; and even in a true RTOS, will compromise real time performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but it seems a overall design problem to me...

Why won't you just set some flag in SysTick and read it somewhere else?

Like:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

volatile bool flag = false; 
//Consider any form of atomicity here
//atomic_bool or LDREX/STREX instructions here. Bitbanding will also work


void sysTickHandler(void) {
  ticks++;
  if (f1_act || f2_act || f3_act) return;
  else {
    flag = true;  //or increment some counter if you want to keep track of the amount of executions
  }
```

And somewhere else:

```
int main() {
  // some init code

  //main loop
  for(;;) {

   foo();//do sth
   bar(x); //do sth else

    if (flag) {
      f1();
      f2();
      f3();
      flag = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or if we assume that every interrupt wakes the microcontroller and power-down mode is needed, then sth. like this might work:

```
if (flag) {
  f1();
  f2();
  f3();
  flag = false;
}
goToSleep(powerDownModeX); //whatever;
```

Comment: Busy waiting is bad design in embedded. If power is a concern, it is a no-go.

Comment: Olaf, I agree with you, but it's just a simplest example possible. If those functions are supposed to be executed every x timer cycles and nothing more will happen, then it would be reasonable to put the microcontroller into sleep mode etc. But we don't know that.

Comment: @Olaf : And yet you were willing to advocate interrupt only processing!?  Both may be bas design; it is application dependent - you cannot be quite so categorical on the evidence before you.

Comment: @Clifford: I don't "advocate" (n)either(?). All I say it depends on the requirements, MCU/CPU capabilities, etc. There is just no simple general good/bad.

Comment: Gentlemen, it really depends on what is needed. I am aware that losing cycles on while-looping is bad if there's nothing else to do. But in case some things in the main loop may be reimplemented in a non-blocking way, then I suppose itwould be a way to go. And again: my examples were supposed to be simple. It's rather impossible to come up with something more complex and appropriate without knowing the details

Comment: @alagner : well said.  In this case the busy-wait would be far less dubious than what the OP is proposing in, and in you example it is not busy-waiting if you assume that foo() and bar() do something useful.

Comment: @Olaf : "There is just no simple general good/bad" - true - but that is not what you said in your initial comment.  You were very specific about it being bad design.

Comment: @Clifford: I stand for my statement, but I forgot there might be MCUs/CPUs which do not have some kind of "wait for interrupt". For those it might be the only alternative. Also, alagner is right as it is just an example. I really should have tagged this as "note" or "additional information" and better worded. Ashes on my head. Let's blame a hard week with lots of useless discussions - at least part of the reason.

Comment: @Olaf : In this case of course the Cortex-M *does* have WFI.